# How to get dynamic select_tag params in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

```
<%= @questions.each do |question| %>
   <%= select_tag "campaign_#{question['id']}",options_from_collection_for_select(current_advertiser.campaigns.all, "id", "title", selected_value || 0) %>
<% end %>
```

Now how I get the selected value in controller. Meanz they are dynamic then how I get `params[?]`

Comment: `campaign_params = [] @questions.each{|q| campaign_params << params[:'campaign_'+q.id.to_s]}`

Comment: Can u ellaborate it in nswer?

Comment: Add controller code to the question then i can add proper code in the answer and also explain what you want to do with the params ?

Comment: I want to get parms[?] in controller . But doesn't know how to get dynamic params

Comment: You will get all params[?] with form submit to controller then what to do with them Kindly explain ?